# Finite Field Grassmannians as Homogeneous Spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, homogeneous-spaces

For the real Grassmannian Gr$(N,k)$ we have the well-known isomorphism 
$$
\text{Gr}(N,k) = O(N)/(O(k) \times O(N-k))
$$ 
For the complex case, we have
$$
\text{Gr}(N,k) = U(N)/(U(k) \times U(N-k))
$$ 
I would like to know if anything like this holds in the finite field setting, ie can the finite field Grassmannians be described as a homogeneous space of an algebraic group over a finite field, or something like this?

Comment: Yes.  It's a homogeneous space over GL of the base field, for all fields.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? What's the stabilizer subgroup, and how does it act on GL? 

Comment: Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian#The_Grassmannian_as_a_homogeneous_space  Which it's considered good form to check *before* asking MO questions.

Comment: Perhaps it should be noted that over finite fields there are "outer forms" of some Grassmannians, e.g., the Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces of a vector space of dimension $2k$.  These are not homogeneous spaces for the "split form" of $\textbf{GL}_{2k}$.  Also, I believe the OP mistakenly wrote $O(1) \times O(N-1)$ instead of $O(k) times O(N-k)$.  

Comment: Yes I did, fixed now.


Comment: You forgot about the $O(1)$ and $U(1)$ [This comment will self-destruct.]

Comment: It should be right now

Answer (score 2):

There is a description of these homogeneous spaces over finite fields in terms of graphs in "Distance-Regular Graphs" by Brouwer, Cohen and Neumaier (Springer, 1989) and in "Algebraic combinatorics I: Association schemes" by E.Bannai and T.Ito (Benjamin/Cummings, 1984).